# Jquery Color Picker how to set certain divs to color change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use this plugin on my website: http://colpick.com/plugin

And I would like to know how I can set it to change certain divs colors like `#panel` and `#thead`

Does it need to be done in the javascript where the color pick is being shown?

```
$('#picker').colpick();
```

or does it need to be in the javascript file or something that comes with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to include the plugin files:

```
<script src="js/colpick.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colpick.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Then you need to create a div:

```
<div class="color-box"></div>
```

And give it some CSS:

```
.color-box {
    float:left;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin:5px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

And finally you can add the jQuery code to it:

```
$('.color-box').colpick({
    colorScheme:'dark',
    layout:'rgbhex',
    color:'ff8800',
    onSubmit:function(hsb,hex,rgb,el) {
        $(el).css('background-color', '#'+hex);
        $(el).colpickHide();
    }
})
.css('background-color', '#ff8800');
```

All this was taken from their website. They have lots of examples on how to work with it.
http://colpick.com/plugin

Comment: so where the panel is I need to add this?

Comment: the panel is something you need to create,.

Comment: the panel is just a div.

Comment: or panel is a div in the css file. do I need to add something there?

Comment: Well I run a forum and have a huge css file so Is there any possible way to just do it without putting everything individually in a color box?